# Isbell duality for profunctors

Tags: ct.category-theory, profunctors

$\def\L{\mathfrak{L}}\def\Prof{\mathsf{Prof}}$Let $A,B$ be two $\cal V$-categories, and define the functor
$$
\L : \Prof(A,B) \to \Prof(B,A)
$$
sending $K : A^° \times B \to \cal V$ into $\L(K) : (b,a)\mapsto {\cal V}^{A^°}(K(-,b), \hom(-,a))$. $\L(K)$ is defined by the "deduction"
$$
\begin{array}{c}
A^° \otimes B \overset{K}{\rightarrow} {\cal V} \qquad A^°\otimes C \overset{F}{\rightarrow}{\cal V} \\ \hline
B^° \otimes A \overset{L(K)}{\rightarrow} {\cal V} \qquad A^°\otimes C \overset{F}{\rightarrow}{\cal V} \\\hline
B^° \otimes A \otimes A^° \otimes C \overset{(L(K),F)}{\rightarrow} {\cal V}\otimes {\cal V} \to {\cal V}\\\hline
B^°\otimes C \overset{\int^{A}L(K)\otimes F}{\rightarrow}  {\cal V}
\end{array}
$$

1. Given $K : A^°\times B\to \cal V$ and $F : A^°\times C \to \cal V$, the coend
   $$
   \int^a \L(K)(-,a) \otimes F(a,-)
   $$
   defines a profunctor $B^°\times C \to \cal V$; does it have a manifest universal property?
2. It is a matter of computation that $\L(\hom(1,F)) = \hom(F,1)$ and hence
   $$
   \L(\hom(1,F)) \dashv \hom(1,F)
   $$ 
   are there other examples of nonrepresentable profunctors $P$ such that $\L(P) \dashv P$?
3. There is a dual construction of a functor $\mathfrak{R}$. Do the dual questions admit dual answers?